# Partial convolution of random variables in random vectors

Tags: distributions, convolution

Suppose $(X_1,Y_1)$ is a bivariate random vector with a given distribution
and let $X_2$ be a univariate random variable with the same distribution
as  $X_1$ but independent of $(X_1,Y_1)$. I want to find the
distribution of $(X_1+X_2,Y_1)$.

As an specific example suppose $(X_1,Y_1)$ is bivariate normal so my
first attempt was the following code:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
TransformedDistribution[{u + w , 
v}, {{u, v} \[Distributed] 
 BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0.5], 
w \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}];

PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], {x, y}]

PDF[
TransformedDistribution[{u + w, 
v}, {{u, v} \[Distributed] 
BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0.5], 
w \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}], {x, y}]

Mean[\[ScriptCapitalD]]

{0, 0}

Covariance[\[ScriptCapitalD]]

{{2., 0.5}, {0.5, 1.}}
```

I have tried some other distributions such as uniform distribution as
 well but I can not get the `PDF` of the joint
 distribution. Although I can find the answer myself by using the
 transformation theory for random variables I wonder if it is
possible to get the results in Mathematica.

Comment: Nothing to add to resolution, other than it's interesting that things like `RandomVariate` work fine on the transformed distribution. Puzzling, *perhaps* a bug.

Comment: I'm sure you've noted the same result using an equivalent `MultinormalDistribution` in the transformed distribution: `PDF` returns unevaluated, even for numeric values, yet other functions on it seem to be fine. Perhaps time for a ping to WRI support.